# I need a plugin in wordpress like google tasks

Tags: customization, plugin-recommendation

I need a plugin like google tasks, in which we can add in to do tasks on the wordpress page

Comment: Instead of just asking "I need a plugin for xxxxx" why don't you first try searching [The WordPress.org Plugin Repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=tasks&sort=) Maybe install a few and test them out then come back here with specific questions related to the plugin or for recommendations for a better one.  I'm voting to close.

Comment: Ditto on *@Chris_O* 's comments.

Comment: Ultimately, the role of this site it to be helped and help others in a very ying yang, give and take sort of way. It it not to have the community do your research.

Comment: Thanks but isint that quite obvious that i had researched and couldnt find thats why I posted here. I had tried and tested many of them but couldnt find the one exactly like google tasks, so if you get bothered with such questions just ignore :)

Comment: Clearly, it isn't obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know Google Tasks. But a Task Manager I use on nearly every blog is [Cleverness To-Do List](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cleverness-to-do-list/). You can order tasks by custom categories and by priority, assign tasks to specific users and set the progress for each task.
Really useful, saves me hundreds of mails from my clients. ;)

Comment: thanks a lot bt in this you cannot add a task in the website right? you have to go all the way in admin section to add a task, in google task you can add a task on the website ( ajax work)

Comment: The plugin offers a widget to show on the front end. I’ve never tried that, so you have to test ist for yourself. Wy do you want your visitors allow to add tasks?

Comment: I am making something like igoogle and zoho desktop, for that i need this feature

Answer (score 0):

You can try [wp-note](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-note/) though it's not as close as google notebook. Because, this plugin will link your notes to posts.